# Jquery use a variable for a load query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a variable but I can't use it the way I want, please help!!

```
var test = window.location.hash;
$('div').load("test.php?id="+test);
```

The request keeps on being :

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/test-site/test.php?id=".
```

and ignores my variable...

Comment: Syntax looks right...are you sure `test` contains something?

Comment: Are you sure `test` isn't blank? Try `console.log(test)`

Comment: `window.location.hash` will begin with a `#` symbol, if it contains anything at all. You should strip it by adding `.substr(1)`.

Comment: I logged it just before and just after it isn't blank...

Comment: thx Blazemonger, that was the problem!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.hash` will begin with a `#` symbol, if it contains anything at all. You should strip it by adding `.substr(1)`:

```
var test = window.location.hash.substr(1);
$('div').load("test.php?id="+test);
```

As it is, you are trying to load a url like `test.php?id=#22`, and since the hash is meaningless for AJAX purposes, it's being ignored by the `.load` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
var test = window.location.hash.substring(1);
```